# Change the add content look and feel for an specific content type?

Tags: 7, forms

So, I would like to change how the Add Content form looks like. Right now the user sees it like this (everything's in spanish, sorry)

[image: "Crear Plato" input form]

But I would like to change it to something like this (all text in spanish again, sorry)

[image: Mockup Form]

The text in grey would be the latest saved node, the button on the right ("Agregar Siguiente") acts like the "save" button, but it comes back immediately to this same page.

I know I would have to develop a Module to do this, could you direct me in the right direction to do something like this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a theme override template for that content type for the edit mode. Then you can style it how you want. See this link for more information about how to do this:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1142800#comment-4433994

Answer (score 0):

you could also take a look at [Panels:](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels)

> The Panels module allows a site administrator to create customized
>   layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag and drop content
>   manager that lets you visually design a layout and place content
>   within that layout. Integration with other systems allows you to
>   create nodes that use this, landing pages that use this, and even
>   override system pages such as taxonomy and the node page so that you
>   can customize the layout of your site with very fine grained
>   permissions.